# TSQL: Get a row which has a max value for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns (id, name) with following values:

```
id    name
---   ---
 1    John
 2    John 
 3    Mary
 4    Mary
```

For values that are repeated in 'name', I only want to select those rows which have maximum value in 'id'. So my desired output is:

```
id    name
---   ---
 2    John
 4    Mary
```

I tried following instructions from this link: [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column) but couldn't get it to work.

This is the query I'm using:

```
select 
    name, id 
from
    (select 
         name, max(id) over (partition by name) max_ID 
     from sometable) 
where 
    id = max_ID
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you alias your subquery you will avoid the syntax error... try putting "AS MyTable" after your closing parenthesis

```
select name, id 
FROM ( select name, max(id) over (partition by name) max_ID from sometable ) AS MyTable 
where id = max_ID
```

This might be simpler though:

```
SELECT name, MAX(id) FROM tablename GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Worth noting that the alias syntax can be "...from sometable) MyTable" or with an "AS" like so, "...from sometable) AS MyTable"

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery has no mandatory alias

```
.. 
FROM ( select name, max(id) over (partition by name) max_ID from sometable )  t -- alias missing 
..
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an alias for an aggregate function in where this is wrong.

Using having  you can select the name with more then one row

```
 select * from my_table where id in (  
 select max(id) from my_table where name in 
 (
   select   name
   from  my_table 
   having count(*) >1 
   group by name )) ;
```